# Using Apache for dynamic path file server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

in Apache htaccess, is there a way to use parameters as sub folders, Without redirecting to the real URL?

for example:

https://example.com/folder1/folder2/a.jpg?version=small

to

https://example.com/folder1/folder2/small/a.jpg

I have tried various things for this but it didn't work.
for example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^version=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.jpg$ $1/%1/$2 [L]
```

note:

I also trying to make the versions folder unavailable in direct request

`RedirectMatch 403 ^/small/?$`

Comment: So _what_ have you tried? Because you will find hundreds of working examples here on SO demonstrating similar things. So please add your best attempt to the question (there is an "edit" button below your question, use it) and explain what exactly you mean my "didn't work". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use dynamic file extensions in the .htaccess file to achieve the desired URL rewriting. To do this, you need to modify the regular expression in the RewriteRule to capture the dynamic extension and use it in the rewritten URL.

Here's how you can achieve this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# Extract the version parameter from the query string 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} version=([^&]+)

# Extract the file extension from the original request 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.(.+)$ $1/%1/$2.%3 L
```

The (.+) in the RewriteRule captures the dynamic file extension, and %3 in the substitution represents that captured extension in the rewritten URL.

Comment: Hi Farid - Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^version=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^/?folder1/folder2/(.+)$ /folder1/folder2/%1/$1 [L,QSD]
```

The `RewriteCond` extracts the *word* specified as "version" parameter, the `RewriteRule` *internally* rewrites the request using the extracted version word and file name.

Very likely you will have to tweak the details in the implementation to match your specific situation.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I get a 500  Internal Server Error When I use the version parameter

Comment: @MajidTabibpour Sorry about that, my fault. I added the "QSD" flag to the rule, which should fix that issue. Without that flag the rewriting engine runs into an endless rewriting loop, since the rewritten URL is again matched by the rule. Dropping the GET argument prevents that.

Comment: @MajidTabibpour In general when receiving a http 500 the first thing you _always_ do is check the http server's log file. That is where you can read the actual issue the server ran into. That is private information which is _not_ shared with requesting clients. In that error log file you will see the endless rewriting loop I pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to adjust the regular expression in the RewriteRule accordingly. Additionally, make sure to backup your .htaccess file before making any changes to avoid potential issues with your website.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Extract the version parameter from the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^version=([^&]+)

# Rewrite the URL with the version parameter as a subfolder
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.jpg$ $1/%1/$2.jpg L
```

The %1 in the RewriteRule refers to the captured value from the RewriteCond directive, which is the version parameter from the query string.